# Showing a question during a video in Android

Tags: android, video

I am trying to implement something similar to what Coursera does when watching a video - ask the user a question to assess his/her understanding like shown below

[image]

[image]

What is a good way to do this in Android - or is this itself a good way ( Full screen video followed by full screen question with options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would be the size of the questions? You need to concentrate more on readability of question, as these questions are for knowing the understanding of user. I would have kept it simple, as they do i.e Full screen video followed by full screen question with options.

Comment: True! Exactly what I had in mind. The questions are generally one liners with simple options and an explanation . I was wondering if this is intuitive for the user, or would a flyout or some mechanism be better so the user always sees the video?

Comment: What I am going with

Answer (score 0):

The questions should definitely overlay the whole screen on Android, because, otherwise, readability could be hindered, due to phone display sizes being much smaller than on PC monitors, especially if the questions are not very short and simple.